# What's the difference between these Google Login methods?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, google-signin

My requirement:

Using google login as the only login method for my website, creating users by google user id, creating authentication sessions after a valid google login.

I saw there was 2 ways to do this:

1. The standard google docs

   (step 1) get id token at frontend https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

   (step 2) verify token id at backend https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth
2. Using spring security OAuth functions

   https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-google-sign-in-in-spring-boot

So the problem is,

1. I just finished implementing measure 1 and found that after the login popup closes the state at frontend is changed. No typical OAuth2 elements like `redirect_uri`, `code` and `access_token` invovled in the process. So is this OAuth at all or is google just packed everything for me so I'm not seeing them?
2. Is measure 2 better? Because you don't have to deal with, let's say, the leak of `id_token` and `client_id` ?

Comment: Here's another one, seems like a real oauth workflow with the code & tokens: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The personas involved are different:

- Front end: web OAuth2 flow with user involved. You request an authorization code with a redirect_uri for redirecting the user after the authentication. And then you validate this authorization code against the IDP server (you need a client ID and a client secret).
- Back end: implicit OAuth2 flow with secret key file for the authentication, for app authentication. This flow is only to deploy on backend server, you absolutely don't have to share your secret key file in your website front end

**EDIT**

With your update, I'm not sure to understand. The 3 are equivalent

- Pure OAuth flow
- Google packaging (the `function onSuccess()` is called when the authentication is successful in the popup, as you can see in [this example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button)
- Spring boot packaging.

At the end, the same information are provided and required, the "leak" are the same in all cases. It's simply a packaging preference and habit.

**EDIT 2**

For getting the access_token or the refresh token, you can simply do this as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse)

```
accessToken = googleUser.reloadAuthResponse().access_token
```

Then, you can pass it to your backend if you want to perform operations on behalf of the user.

Comment: Actually I mean these Frontend/Backend integration are used together.

I clarified my problem in a more detailed way. Sorry for the ambiguous content!

Comment: OK. I see. So the OAuth flow is completed by Google JS SDK. Then Google JS SDK passes the id_token through onSuccess. Finally I can pass the id_token like passing a JWT to the backend. In the process concepts like `access_token` are not seen by me. So that means there's no way for me to log out purely using backend (just like JWT cannot do this either)?

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I get it now